# Why does Google Images draw images using canvas?

Tags: html, canvas

**Updated:** Google Images does not use `<canvas>` any more.

---

I noticed [Google Images](http://www.google.com/images) is using canvas to render images. `<img>` is used as a fallback for browsers that does not support canvas.

```
<a class="rg_l" style="..." href="...">
  <canvas
    id="cvs_NcG8skPEDu7FWM:b"
    style="display:block"
    width="83"
    height="113">
  </canvas>
  <img 
    class="rg_i"
    id="NcG8skPEDu7FWM:b"
    data-src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCB5NEbEUQhtmFI098HLSkfmoHTBtUfERUNkNKrhgFbtFBxZXY9ejXn_pUGg"
    height="113"
    width="83"
    style="width:83px;height:113px"
    onload="google.isr.fillCanvas(this);google.stb.csi.onTbn(0, this)"
    src="http://t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQCB5NEbEUQhtmFI098HLSkfmoHTBtUfERUNkNKrhgFbtFBxZXY9ejXn_pUGg">
</a>
```

What's the point of using `<canvas>` rather than `<img>`?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it gives them **more control** over the contents of an image.

You can analyze color range of an image, prevailing color, even its content (given smart algorithm).

You can also perform per-pixel modifications — change brightness, contrast, gamma, etc. (not sure why they would want to do this; perhaps for some future use).

You can also rotate an image (on browsers that support canvas but not CSS transformations; see, for example, this [demo of my fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo/)).

Answer (score 4):

Several mobile devices have a limit on the number of image resources on one page. For example, [Mobile Safari stops loading images after ± 6.5 MB of images have been loaded](http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2010/05/05/ipad-safari-image-limit-workaround/).

As mentioned in another answer, by using `<canvas>` instead of several `<img>` elements with external files as their `src`, Google can load all the images in one request (which is obviously better for performance) — but it also works around this limitation.

Answer (score 3):

- You can easily load all the images in one request or even embed their source in the page without inflating the source with base64.
- You can make copies of images in JS without waiting for the cache.

Comment: I can dynamically create <img src="data:image/jpg;base64..."> elements as well as canvas elements. Same with the copies. I don't see any benefits.

Comment: How do I load all images in one request without using base64 encoding? Although, Google doesn't load them in a single request.

Comment: @NV: Escape all occurences of ` \ ` and `|` and seperate them with `|` or so

Comment: Hummm... on the other side, you could also send it to the client this way and base64-encode there. Maybe Google just did it to make people use newer browsers?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this was done because of too slow scrolling / some rendering issues on a page with lots of pictures?